# Equivalent time sampling with an ADC

Tags: adc, latch

ETS can be used to sample repetitive signals with a high virtual resolution.
Lets say we have repititive 1MHz signal we want to sample. This signal can be sampled with ETS.
For example a comparator inside a delta modulator structure can be latched with a frequency that is minimal smaller than 1MHz to reconstruct the signal on a slower timescale and improve the temporal resolution. The problem is that a delta modulator has a limited amplitude resolution.

Can ETS also be used with a "normal" 16 Bit ADC? If yes how is the latching done?

Comment: what's "normal" ADCs (or "not normal" about \$\Sigma\Delta\$ ADCs?)? I think you're on to something, but I'm not sure what specifically you're looking for, and I don't want to waste a page writing over differences in sample-and-hold approaches if that's not what you care about.

Comment: @MarcusMüller inside a Delta ADC (not Sigma Delta) their is only one comparator, this one can be latched for ETS. With normal ADC I mean something like this one https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=26&gotoUrl=http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads112u04.pdf

Comment: ah, sorry, misread. But yeah, the problem here is the sampling period. The ADC you've chosen is pretty "special" in that it has an UART interface (notice: asynchronous...), so even if the Sigma Delta capture period wasn't a problem, it would kind of be the worst possible choice – there's very many ADCs that have a "capture trigger" input, if that answers that part of your question.

Comment: @MarcusMülle ok thanks alot I just needed the technical term for further research. You can post this as an aswer so I can close this question

Comment: I'm surprised! What term where you missing? I didn't "mean" to answer your question (glad I did, though :) ), but I don't know what to put in an answer?

Comment: @MarcusMüller the "capture trigger" term

Comment: ah! Yeah, but as said, that's but half the business – other ADC architectures might simply not work.

Comment: @MarcusMüller do you mean other ADC architecutres beside SigmaDelta? 
Could you link me one ADC with a capture trigger input please?

Comment: Honestly, almost all ADCs that don't have a low speed serial interface have a conversion start or capture trigger input. There's pages after pages on analog.com and ti.com of these.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ok I found one https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads8471.pdf?ts=1610546507367&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS8471